# Facebook Graph API only returns 4 friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&fields=name,gender,picture.width(1000)
```

When I request that Facebook returns the profile pictures and data of the user's friend list using the method above it only returns four results (four friends).

Is it possible to add a parameter to the above method to return all of the user's friends (or to set some limit for the number of friends to display)?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get friends who authorized your App with `user_friends`.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: I am getting 4 friends who never authorized the app though. Is there a way that I can get the profile pictures of all of the user's friends when they use the app?

Comment: if that´s the case, then it´s a bug. you should not get any friends who did not authorize your app. of course you can get the profile pics of friends who authorized your app: me/friends?fields=name,picture - you do have the correct api call in your question already.

Comment: btw, maybe you are trying this api call in the api explorer with the api explorer app? in that case, you get all the friends who authorized that official app.